# Webpack Babel - Module build failed: TypeError: Cannot read property 'bindings' of nul

Tags: vue.js, webpack, babeljs

I'm building a new project in VUEJS 2 and am having a issue. I'm fairly new to webpack so I'm learning it as I go. Can you tell me why this section of code throws an error?

> ./store/modules/user/store.js

```
const state = {
    user: {}
};
```

Then when it gets compiled, webpack throws these errors:

```
ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 errors                                                                         14:21:50
 error  in ./assets/js/store/modules/user/store.js

Module build failed: TypeError: Cannot read property 'bindings' of null
    at Scope.moveBindingTo (c:\myProject\node_modules\@babel\traverse\lib\scope\index.js:978:13)
    at BlockScoping.updateScopeInfo (c:\myProject\node_modules\babel-plugin-transform-es2015-block-scoping\lib\index.js:364:17)
    at BlockScoping.run (c:\myProject\node_modules\babel-plugin-transform-es2015-block-scoping\lib\index.js:330:12)
    at PluginPass.BlockStatementSwitchStatementProgram (c:\myProject\node_modules\babel-plugin-transform-es2015-block-scoping\lib\index.js:70:24)
    at newFn (c:\myProject\node_modules\@babel\traverse\lib\visitors.js:237:21)
    at NodePath._call (c:\myProject\node_modules\@babel\traverse\lib\path\context.js:65:20)
    at NodePath.call (c:\myProject\node_modules\@babel\traverse\lib\path\context.js:40:17)
    at NodePath.visit (c:\myProject\node_modules\@babel\traverse\lib\path\context.js:100:12)
    at TraversalContext.visitQueue (c:\myProject\node_modules\@babel\traverse\lib\context.js:142:16)
    at TraversalContext.visitSingle (c:\myProject\node_modules\@babel\traverse\lib\context.js:102:19)
    at TraversalContext.visit (c:\myProject\node_modules\@babel\traverse\lib\context.js:182:19)
    at Function.traverse.node (c:\myProject\node_modules\@babel\traverse\lib\index.js:106:17)
    at traverse (c:\myProject\node_modules\@babel\traverse\lib\index.js:76:12)
    at transformFile (c:\myProject\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\transformation\index.js:116:29)
    at runSync (c:\myProject\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\transformation\index.js:45:3)
    at runAsync (c:\myProject\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\transformation\index.js:35:14)
    at process.nextTick (c:\myProject\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\transform.js:34:34)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)

 @ ./assets/js/store/store.js 3:0-40
 @ ./assets/js/main.js
```

> Here is my package.json

```
{
    "devDependencies": {
        "@symfony/webpack-encore": "^0.17.0",
        "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^3.0.0-rc.3",
        "@vue/test-utils": "^1.0.0-beta.20",
        "babel-core": "^7.0.0-bridge.0",
        "babel-jest": "^23.2.0",
        "node-sass": "^4.9.0",
        "sass-loader": "^7.0.3",
        "vue-loader": "^14.1.1",
        "vue-template-compiler": "^2.5.16"
    },
    "license": "UNLICENSED",
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev-server": "encore dev-server",
        "dev": "encore dev",
        "watch": "encore dev --watch",
        "build": "encore production"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^7.0.0-beta.51",
        "@coreui/coreui": "^2.0.3",
        "@coreui/coreui-plugin-chartjs-custom-tooltips": "^1.2.0",
        "@coreui/icons": "0.2.0",
        "@coreui/vue": "^2.0.0-rc.0",
        "axios": "^0.18.0",
        "bootstrap": "^4.1.1",
        "bootstrap-vue": "^2.0.0-rc.11",
        "chart.js": "^2.7.2",
        "core-js": "^2.5.7",
        "css-vars-ponyfill": "^1.7.2",
        "flag-icon-css": "^3.0.0",
        "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
        "jquery": "^3.3.1",
        "npm": "^6.4.0",
        "perfect-scrollbar": "^1.4.0",
        "simple-line-icons": "^2.4.1",
        "sweetalert2": "^7.26.11",
        "vue": "^2.5.16",
        "vue-chartjs": "^3.3.2",
        "vue-perfect-scrollbar": "^0.1.0",
        "vue-router": "^3.0.1",
        "vue-table-component": "^2.0.0-alpha.1",
        "vue-tables": "^1.6.44",
        "vuetable": "^1.5.12",
        "vuex": "^3.0.1"
    }
}
```

I'm assuming i'm missing some sort of babel extension. I've done some research and think it might be something to do with es2015 not being understood in the "store.js" file. Any idea on what I could do fix this? I also noticed I don't have a .babelrc file, is there something I need to put in that so this will work?

I appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by just reverting to react-native@0.55.4 for now.I'm also faced error by using (react-native@0.56)@babel/core 7.0.0-beta.